# PCollection Sideinput: Feeding a single String as a SideInput to a PCollection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to feed a ParDo on a PCollection with a single String as a SideInput. I tried the following:

```
PCollection<String> sideView = p.apply(Create.of(sideName).withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));
final PCollectionView<String> filterObject = sideView.apply(View.asSingleton());
```

But I am running into a compilation error:

```
no suitable method found for apply(View.asSingleton())
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing? I poked around the SDK javadoc a lot but  I could not find anything specific to solve this problem which seems so trivial. :(

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the compilation error message?

Comment: I get an error like `no suitable method found for apply(View.asSingleton())` which obviously means I am missing something very basic. The problem is that I could not find any examples using side-inputs created inline and so, kind of worked around this without using the side-input at all

Comment: Try View.<String>asSingleton() ? (that's the way it's used in the examples: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=assingleton)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your error would be something like:

```
The method apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<String>,OutputT>)
in the type PCollection<String> is not applicable for the arguments
(View.AsSingleton<Object>)
```

This is because type inference in the Java compiler in the presence of generics is not perfect and in this case it is required to add an explicit type parameter:

```
final PCollectionView<String> filterObject =
    sideView.apply(View.<String>asSingleton());
```

Indeed, usages of `View.asSingleton` in the Dataflow SDK examples specify this parameter: see [github search](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=assingleton).

However, as of writing, our javadocs and public documentation fail to mention this. We'll fix that, thanks for the report!